# TEXTPTR in SQLITE

Tags: sql, xml, sqlite

I am searching for alternative to TEXTPTR in SQLite.

I have a query in sql server 2005 express edition like:

```
SELECT @ptrval = TEXTPTR(STATUS_XML) 
  FROM JOB_STATUS_XML 
WHERE job_guid = @JobGuid 

UPDATETEXT JOB_STATUS_XML.STATUS_XML @ptrval @Pointer 5 @Result
```

I have to convert it to a SQLite query.

Comment: You have larger issues, like how SQLite supports XML...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT column_name = 'something' FROM tabel_name WHERE column_name = 'something'

UPDATE tabel_name SET column_name = 'something' WHERE column_name = 'something'
```

I hope this help !!!